# How to Create session for customer login with session outside magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-connect

I am building a small web services code to where I need to have Magento customer login.

But I am not able to create the session. If I create the session from `core/session` it remains same for all users.

**Question 1:** Where are the sessions stored in the database?

**Question 2:** How to create a customer session (`customer/session`) and then fetch that on different locations with the same session ID??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include Mage.php from Magento in your external application

```
// Include Magento application
require_once ( "/your-magento-directory/app/Mage.php" );
umask(0);
     
// Initialize Magento
Mage::app("default");
```

You have two options then, for the session name,
"frontend" for frontend session or "adminhtml" for admin session:

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
```

This will get the session of the current logged in user.

#### And this will login to Magento from outside:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session->login($row['mail'], $row['field_magentopass_value']);
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());
```

`$row['mail']` is the email with user is registered
`$row['field_magentopass_value']` is the password

<sup>**Source:**
http://louisjohn.wordpress.com/category/magento/magento-functions-outside-magento-folder/</sup>

Comment: To Login 
$session->login($row['mail'], row['field_magentopass_value']);

what is the values to pass:
$row['mail'] is replaced by customers mail id but what about the another one?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it earlier. edited the answer. please check

Comment: Sir I am getting 500 error when I am using this.
I tried password and also hash value from db also. But 500 error is coming up

Comment: @HarsimranSingh:I don't know why it throws 500 error. but make sure the paths are correct.I use this to login from drupal 7 to magento 1.7 CE.I verified it now once again

Comment: Sorry was a minor mistake of mine.. But Logged n how to check whether the logged in user is same? like session id or email to check with?

Comment: @HarsimranSingh:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982210/how-to-access-magento-customers-session-from-outside-magento

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9007/discussion-between-harsimran-singh-and-zamil)