# Customer Session outside Magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, customer, session

I would like to know if it is possible to fetch the Magento customer session outside Magento and how to go about it.

For example if my Magento instance is in a folder with the path : `"public_html/Magento"` and if I have a php file with the path `"public_html/abc.php"` i.e outside the Magento folder, can I check if a user is logged in on Magento (& also get cart details) on `abc.php`?

I've tried various solutions out there (like including `Mage.php` & fetching the session), which were mostly similar to [How to Create session for customer login with session outside magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4254/how-to-create-session-for-customer-login-with-session-outside-magento)
but I wasn't able to check if the customer is logged in and get the cart item details on `abc.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the cookie containing the session named `frontend` is not available on your `abc.php` script.

Make sure the cookie path in your Magento installation is set to `/` under
`System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management > Cookie Path` and install an extension in your browser that can easily display cookies. In chrome I use *edit this cookie*.

Comment: I'd already checked that. It was set to / only. But still I was unable to get the details.
And / would refer to the magento root directory and not the root directory of the server... if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Instead of  **/**  I've set the Cookie Path to    /Magento_folder_name/
and I used the method mentioned in this link **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764296/magento-session-from-external-page-same-domain** & it seems to work fine.
Anyways thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This worked for me.  I've got a script in a sub-dir of public_html and it was creating a `frontend` cookie with the `path` set to the sub-dir.  So there were then two `frontend` cookies but with different paths.

Setting the cookie path in Magento Admin to '/' fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the cookie `frontend` is passed to your `abc.php`. If yes, you can load the session with magento.

include `Mage.php`, `Mage::app()` and get the session `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->start()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
// Define the path to the root of Magento installation.
define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "Customer is logged in";}
else{
    echo "Customer is not logged in";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you might not be sending the required session id through Cookie "frontend" as mentioned in few replies. Alternatively you can also pass on Session id through URL query parameter "SID". So if you are making a call to URL "http://yourmagentoserver/products/pots". Then your URL will be "http://yourmagentoserver/products/pots?SID=your session id"